# Customizing width and height for child view controller does not work

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller

I'm trying to set the width and height of my child view controller's frame, but it's not working. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
  let frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
  let vc = FieldsTableViewController()
  addChild(vc)
  view.addSubview(vc.view)        
  vc.didMove(toParent: self)
  vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: (frame.maxX+frame.minX)/2, y: 300, width: 200, height: 5)
```

The x and y positions are correctly set, but no matter what I try I can't seem to set the width and the height. The weird thing is that I am using the same child vc in another vc, with the exact same code as above, and I have no problem setting the width and height there.

I also tried using Auto-Layout but was not able to make it work for a child view controller (is that possible? I didn't find any example).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at `UIContainerView`? It handles pretty much all of the work for you.

Comment: My understanding is that UIContainerView only exists in storyboard, because it is actually just an UIView.  I think that I'm already doing the "programmatical" equivalent of UIContainerView. 
I don't use storyboards at all (maybe I should specify it whenever I post a question?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it.
I finally realized that the issue occurs when I set the view of my view controller, like so :

```
let v = PlayerSelectionView()
view = v
```

I'm not sure why that caused the problem described, but adding my view as a subview instead fixed it:

```
let v = PlayerSelectionView()
v.frame = view.frame
view.addSubview(v)
```

Now I'm able to edit the width and height of my child view controllers.